The norm of a unitarily equivalent matrix to a diagonal matrix is equal to $1$.
Suppose that $A$ is unitarily equivalent to a diagonal matrix $D$ whose diagonal entries are the
eigenvalues of $A$, namely $λ_1,\cdots, λ_n$. I'm asked to compute $∥A∥$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$.
Here $$||A||=max_{x\in \mathbb C^n\setminus 0}\; \dfrac{||Ax||_2}{||x||_2}$$
So since $A$ is unitarily equivalent to a diagonal matrix $D$ then we can show that $||A||=||D||$
Hence $$||A||=||D||=max_{x\in \mathbb C^n\setminus 0}\; \dfrac{||Dx||_2}{||x||_2}$$
But $$||Dx||_2=\sqrt{|\lambda_1|^2|x_1|^2+\cdots+|\lambda_n|^2|x_n|^2}$$
and since $A$ is unitary its eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are with modulus equal to $1$ hence $|\lambda_i|^2=1$ hence
$$||Dx||_2=\sqrt{|x_1|^2+\cdots+|x_n|^2}=||x||_2$$
Consequently,
$$||A||=||D||=max_{x\in \mathbb C^n\setminus 0}\; \dfrac{||x||_2}{||x||_2}=1$$
Is my answer correct? I'm confused about the question which asks the norm to be in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ whereas it is equal to $1$. Am I missing something?

"and since $A$ is unitary..." Is $A$ unitary? You never mentioned that $A$ must be unitary previously in the question. But yes, aside from this surprise assumption, everything looks fine: if $A$ is unitarily equivalent to $D$, then $|A| = |D|$, and if we further assume $A$ is unitary itself, then $|A| = 1$. Note also that matrices that are unitarily equivalent to a unitary matrix are also unitary themselves, and hence preserve norms, hence why the spectral norm does indeed come to $1$.

Not every real diagonal matrix is unitary. A matrix unitarily equivalent to a diagonal matrix need not be unitary.

yes I see what's wrong I assumed $A$ was unitary wich is not true.  Thank you! Should the answer be $||A||=max |\lambda_i|$

Also, FYI, a matrix $A$ is unitarily equivalent to a diagonal matrix if and only if $A$ is normal, i.e. $A^A = AA^$, c.f. the Spectral Theorem.
